# Difference between eval and backticks (reverse apostrophe)

Tags: bash, eval

Can anyone tell me what the big difference here is and why the latter doesn't work?

```
test="ls -l"
```

Both now work fine:

```
eval $test
echo `$test`
```

But in this case:

```
test="ls -l >> test.log"

eval $test
echo `$test`
```

The latter will not work. Why is that? I know that eval is just executing a script while the apostrophes are executing it and return the result as a string. What makes it not possible to use `>>` or simmilar stuff inside the command to execute? Maybe is there a way to make it work with apostrophes and I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: they are called `backticks`.

Comment: @dogbane, oh that was a part of the question also :D Thanks, didn't know how they were called.

Comment: To answer your last question: Yes, you are doing something wrong. If you are using eval or putting code to be executed in strings you are doing something wrong 99.9% of the time. Your script will be harder to reason about, harder to debug, and there are security issues: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're using backticks to execute your command, the command being sent to the shell is:

```
ls -l '>>' test.log
```

which makes both `>>` and `test.log` arguments to `ls` (note the quotes around `>>`).

While using `eval`, the command being executed is:

```
ls -l >> test.log
```

(Execute your script by saying `bash -vx scriptname` to see what's happening.)

Comment: Well I kinda got it out of the error info, but why is that happening? Is there a way to prevent it with backticks?

Comment: @KeluThatsall In the first case, everything including the redirection `>>` is a part of a string and is interpreted literally.

Comment: Does it mean, that backticks are actually splitting the string they are interpreting with spaces and take the first element as a command, and the later as parameters? And you just cannot do anything about that?

Comment: Yes, you can't do *anything* about it.  Either use `eval` or something like: `test="ls -l"; $(test) >> "test.log"`.

Comment: If string is split up like that, then why isn't it when doing just \`ls -l >> test.log\` - these backticks work and produce a file! why isn't \`$something\` <=> \`contentOfSomething\` ?

Comment: @JohnyTex I think it is $ does the var expanding and wordspliting and that 's why we usually put double quotes around $.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789079/bash-eval-replacement-not-always-equivalent
https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

Answer (score 0):

eval is 'expression value' i.e.

```
test="ls -l >> test.log"
eval $test
```

is execute in same way in terminal as

```
ls -l >> test.log
```

whether

echo is for display purpose only.

Comment: I know what that is, I'm asking why the same command doesn't work with backticks.